# Calculating the cross product of 2 vectors without using the torque formula

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, rotational-dynamics, torque

For the scenario described as the follows:

> Two vectors $\vec{s}$ and $\vec{t}$ lie in the xy plane. Their directions are, respectively,
> a° and b° measured counterclockwise from
> the positive x axis. Find the magnitude and the direction of $\vec{s}\times\vec{t}$

I read that the magnitude of $\vec{s}\times\vec{t}$ is calculated by $rs|sin(a°-b°)|$. I'm confused as to why we can calculate it using sin(a°-b°) and what's the geometrical/physical meaning of doing it this way. Based on my knowledge, the only way I came up with is moving $\vec{t}$ so that its tail is at the head of $\vec{s}$. then we can calculate it as if calculating the torque using $\tau=Fl$
[image]

Comment: What do you want to compute? The torque $\vec F\times \vec r$?

Comment: Roughly speaking, the magnitude of the cross product is the determinant of matrice given by the two vectors expressed on the plane they are defined within. And the geometrical interpretation of this determinant is that it is the area of the parallelogram given by these two vectors. Hence you have a $\sin$ function.

Comment: @kyril I want to compute $\vec{s}\times\vec{t}$, but I don't understand the solution described in my question as I only know how to calculate 2 vectors as if calculating a torque...

Comment: I'm sorry I'd like to help, but I don't understand what $s$ and $t$ are...

Answer (score 1):

The magnitude of the vector product of s and t is: st[sin(angle between s and t)].  In the given problem, that angle is the difference between the two angles measured from the x axis.  In your diagram, s would be the radius and t would be F, but there is no reason to assume that F is vertical, and you have not specified the angles from the x axis (assumed horizontal?).

Answer (score 1):

## Why $\sin(a^{\circ} - b^{\circ})$ is used.

(Since you asked in the question content)

The reason for using $\sin(a^{\circ} - b^{\circ})$ is to calculate the angle *between* the two vectors. Similarly as to how $|\vec{s}\cdot\vec{t}|=|s||t|\cos(\theta)$ (Where $\theta$ is the angle between $\vec{s}$ and $\vec{t}$) $|\vec{s}\times\vec{t}|=|s||t|\sin(\theta)$.

Since both $\vec{s}$ and $\vec{t}$ are in the same x-y plane and have known angles measured from the same origin point, the relative angle *between* them can be found by simply subtracting one angle from the other.

Here you can see the vectors and the angles that define them visualised.
[image: Two Vectors with their angles to the positive x axis labelled a° and b° respectively. b° is smaller than a°]

If you then subtract b° from a° you get the following:
[image: Those same vectors but a° and b° are gone. In their place is a single angle starting at one vector and ending at the other labelled "a° - b°"]

Sorry if it was a poor explaination, but that's the reason why $\sin(a^{\circ} - b^{\circ})$ is used.

## Alternate methods of calculating $|\vec{s}\times\vec{t}|$

### Method 1

**Disclaimer: This method will only work for this specific case, since both $\vec{s}$ and $\vec{t}$ share the x-y plane.**
(This method requires the vectors be fully in the x-y plane, with no z component. They also must be in component form.)

Since s and t are in the x-y plane and have no z values, their cross product will only ever have a single z component: x and y will both be zero.
In this case, the magnitude will be the absolute value of this z component, defined as $s_x \cdot t_y - s_y \cdot t_x$.

Thus, in this specific case: $|\vec{s}\times\vec{t}|=|s_x \cdot t_y - s_y \cdot t_x|$

### Method 2

This method takes advantage of the dot formulas and that $\cos(\theta)^{2} + \sin(\theta)^{2} = 1$

We can rearrange the pythagorean identity to get $\sin(\theta) = \sqrt{1 - \cos(\theta)^{2}}$
By plugging this into our formula for the cross product, we get $|\vec{s}\times\vec{t}|=|s||t|\sqrt{1 - \cos(\theta)^{2}}$

With some rearranging:

$$|\vec{s}\times\vec{t}|=|s||t|\sin(\theta)$$
$$|\vec{s}\times\vec{t}|=|s||t|\sqrt{1 - \cos(\theta)^{2}}\tag*{(1)}$$

$$|\vec{s}\cdot\vec{t}|=|s||t|\cos(\theta)$$
$$\cos(\theta)=\frac{|\vec{s}\cdot\vec{t}|}{|s||t|}\tag*{(2)}$$

$$|\vec{s}\cdot\vec{t}| = |s_x \cdot t_x + s_y \cdot t_y \tag*{(3)}|$$

$$\cos(\theta) = \frac{|s_x \cdot t_x + s_y \cdot t_y|}{|s||t|}\tag*{(3) in (2): (4)}$$

$$|\vec{s}\times\vec{t}|=|s||t|\sqrt{1 - (\frac{|s_x \cdot t_x + s_y \cdot t_y|}{|s||t|})^{2}}\tag*{(4) in (1)}$$

$$|\vec{s}\times\vec{t}|=\sqrt{(|s||t|)^{2}} \sqrt{1 - \frac{|s_x \cdot t_x + s_y \cdot t_y|^{2}}{(|s||t|)^{2}}}$$

Thus, with that rearrangement we can find that :
$$|\vec{s}\times\vec{t}|=\sqrt{|s|^{2}|t|^{2} - |s_x \cdot t_x + s_y \cdot t_y|^{2}}$$

Those are two other methods of getting the magnitude of the cross product without using the torque formula, however they both require the vectors to be in component form. I'd personally recommend using just the original $|\vec{s}\times\vec{t}|=|s||t||\sin(a° - b°)|$ for the problem provided, however.

Answer (score -1):

Well you are not wrong but it would ethically be an injustice to physics if we described it that way .
This is because cross product comes first and then torque. So we say that $\tau$ is the cross product of $\vec S$ and $\vec F$ and not the other way round.$$\vec \tau = \vec S \times \vec F$$  It was simply defined that cross product of two vectors $\vec A$ and $\vec B$ is AB$sin \theta$ ($\theta$ being the angle between the two vectors) and have direction as given by screw rule because many quantities like torque were found to obey such results. Besides it is the only way where we can define pseudo vectors like torque that describe motion not along a line but along a plane and are directed perpendicular to such a plane .

Answer (score -1):

Here is another way to evaluate the vector cross product of two vectors using a determinate.

For any two vectors $\vec s$ and $\vec t$
$$\ {\vec s \times \vec t} = \begin{vmatrix} \vec i & \vec j & \vec k \\ s_x & s_y & s_z \\ t_x & t_y & t_z \end{vmatrix}$$ $\vec i$, $\vec j$, and $\vec k$ are unit vectors along the $x$, $y$, and $z$ axes of a Cartesian coordinate system. $s_x$ , $s_y$, and $s_z$ are the components of $\vec s$ along the axes, and  $
t_x$ , $t_y$, and $t_z$ are the components of $\vec t$ along the axes.